# Invalid measurement data removing

Tags: dataset, smoothing

I have a lot of data (temperatures and similar things) collected using automatic devices. Lots of these data is let's call it smooth: even when the temperature increases/decreases fast there are few points indicating that fact like in the figure 1. Unfortunately there also are a lot of data indicating that something was wrong with measuring device, and there are unnatural peaks like in figure 2. I would like to remove that picks - I can always write a simple algorithm removing those episodes. But I am curious if there is some "smart" filter for doing this. I tried moving average and moving median but that distorts data, and when high peaks occur isn't especially effective.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the peak you see in figure 2 an error? It looks like what would happen if you had a peak twice as fast as in figure 1, but your sample rate was too slow to capture the full shape of the curve.

Comment: I am sure these are picks. On the x-axis there is no time scale, therefore it looks like possible thing. However the system I am examining cannot behave such way, it has too big temeprature inertia.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment, you say that the pattern in diagram 2 is impossible because your system has "too big temperature inertia". This implies that you have some criteria for deciding what is impossible.

Then, if you can formalize these criteria, you can write code to find violations. That would be more of a programming issue than a statistical one. You acknowledge this in your question.

But the "smart filter" is your brain and your substantive knowledge.

TL:DR  No, without more detail, there is no such thing.